# which one of these statement's grammar correct

Tags: grammar

1. It will be 3 by the time I reach office
2. It will be 3 by the time I'll reach office.

Comment: It is always recommended to wait until you have received at least three answers before awarding someone. Not everyone at EL&U are native speakers, and those who are, are not always infallible. Good answers will usually receive upvotes, and vice versa.

Comment: Neither one correct -- both examples need article before _office_. Also, your question no verb. Need _is_.

Comment: @John: Also feel need to point out your final sentence no subject.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

the first one is good.

the second sentence needs editing. it should be "it will be 3 by the time I get to the office" or "by the time I will reach the office, it'll be 3".

Comment: Hi
can you tell me why 1st one is correct and why "by the time I will reach the office, it'll be 3" is correct and "It will be 3 by the time I'll reach office." is incorrect

Comment: it is not incorrect, and that is why I wrote it needs editing. formally, the word "office" in the second sentence needs to be preceded by an article. in this case, "the". it should be "it'll be 3 by the time I will reach the office".

Comment: 2. It'll be 3 by the time I'll reach *the* office.

Comment: This is wrong. Native speakers simply don't say *"by the time I will reach the office"*. It's *always* either *"by the time I **reached** the office"* if reporting on events that happened in the past, or *"by the time I **reach** the office"* for future or hypothetical events.

Comment: @FumbleFingers are you referring to Tucker's comment or to both? The first sentence in the question is not correct. It should be: **It'll be** *three by the time* **I reach the** *office*

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I'm referring to the answer *and* the comments, which both include the same error. Not to mention which as of right now the OP has also clearly been *misled* by this incorrect advice (he's repeated the tense error in his comment, *and* accepted the erroneous answer). The "tensed" clause which ***identifies*** whatever time is being referenced is always past or *present*. Any further references to that time are almost always past or *future* as appropriate.

Comment: It will be 2020 by the time I take office.

Comment: Another valid combination of tenses occurs in "present tense narrative" contexts, where both the "identifying" and the "associated" events/actions may be referenced using present tense verb forms. As in... [*by the time **he reaches** {somewhere} **he is** exhausted".](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22by+the+time+he+reaches%22+%22he+is+exhausted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But that's a fairly unusual (often, "literary" usage).